# Defining properties of UI using Attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

For a new project, I was recently asked to investigate a method of attaching information related to UI rendering to business objects in a WPF application. For example a report class:

```
class ExecutionReport
{
    [Displayable(Bold, Background=Color.Red)]
    public String OrderId{get; private set;}

    [Displayable(Normal, HAlignment=Center)]
    public String Symbol {get; private set;}

    // this should be hidden as it doesn't have DisplayableAttribute
    public String ClientOrderId {get; private set;}]

    [Displayable(Normal, HAlignment=Right, 
        Format("If [Position] < 0 then Background=Color.Red"), 
        Format("If [Position] > 0 then Background=Color.Lime"),
        DisplayFormat("+#;-#;0")]
    public Int Position {get; private set;}
}
```

This is a very new approach for me as typically in most wpf MVVM applications I have worked on there has been a clear separation of the view and viewmodel and I strive as much as possible to keep UI specific details out of the VM. Instead I would lean towards writing this using resource dictionaries and simple converters applied on the bindings in the view layer.

My questions are: Are there any wpf/mvvm frameworks out there that use this kind of an implementation? If so I'm curious to see how it would be achieved.

Are there any obvious pitfalls? The first couple things that come to my mind are

- Change notification (ie. INotifyPropertyChanged to trigger an update of the view). Would the implementation of this be a lot harder now?
- Difficulty in being able to leverage resource dictionaries for system wide values. For example, maybe I wanted to change the color of red being used throughout the application. I would have to ctrl + f through and find every place in business objects where it was used and change it instead of being able to modify a single StaticResource
- Inability to leverage DesignTime DataContexts
- Performance. Seems likes this would require heavy use of reflection which might not be as performant as typical value converters

I'm very interested to see if I'm correct on the second and third points or if both of these things could still be acheived?

Ultimately I feel that this is a bad design and I'm leaning towards writing a different implementation to show the interested party how I would typically approach this kind of problem. Just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious that might actually make this more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is very popular and it's called aspect oriented programming (ASP.NET MVC leverages it a lot). The most popular library to write this fast is  [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) (see customers case studies, there are some companies which have used it for WPF). The best thing in PostSharp is that uses **compile-time weaving.**

For the first point: 
PostSharp got well tested `NotifyPropertyChanged` aspect, you can add `[NotifyPropertyChanged]` attribute to class and all properties will call `PropertyChanged` when value gets changed.

For the second point: you can always make your attribute to look for `StaticResources` and pass resource key in attribute.

For the third (although I'm not 100% sure about it) and fourth point: **compile time weaving** means that aspect is "appended" to code on compilation - like you would have written it inside method/property to which you have appended attribute. It's like post-build compiler and doesn't use reflection (if aspect you wrote doesn't use reflection) so performance is really good.

However in example you gave I'd rather go with value converters and styles like @AwkwardCoder said - but aspects(attributes) are also useful with "view" for example: they're great for validiation.

Comment: does AOP support debugging or are they all weaved after compile time?

Answer (score 3):

IMO this seems like a horrible idea, they all seems like examples that should be implemented as XAML converters.

All of the points list seem to be valid reasons to avoid doing this.

Note: There are a set of attributes in the framework which provide some UI functionality already (very limited), see the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this seems like a horrible idea, and your comment ...

> in most wpf MVVM applications I have worked on there has been a clear
>   separation of the view and viewmodel and I strive as much as possible
>   to keep UI specific details out of the VM. Instead I would lean
>   towards writing this using resource dictionaries and simple converters
>   applied on the bindings in the view layer

... I think sums up why and how to avoid it.

Tying your business objects directly to implementation details such as colour, horizontal alignment, or position, seems like a short-term win (but long term hell).